# Best practice storing language variables in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

Given a certain asp.net (or any other language for that matter) website where you want the language strings to be stored together instead of hard-coding them within the aspx page. My friend says you need to store them all in the Web.config. I think the web.config is not made for that and doesn't make sense to put it there. If you have a website containing 2000 language strings in three languages, the webconfig would contain 6000 entries. I think it's better to store them in a table in a database but he doesn't believe me, who's right?

Comment: You could follow this approach - [Walkthrough: Using Resources for Localization with ASP.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/fw69ke6f%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: The standard way is to use resource files, but it's also possible and valid to store the strings in a database table, which makes maintenance much easier. There's an example of how to achieve this via a custom resource provider here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14190/ASP-NET-2-0-Custom-SQL-Server-ResourceProvider

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Database is better than web.config for sure, but I would suggest looking into the [built-in resource functionality](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fw69ke6f%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) before going and making your own system.

Answer (score 1):

No, they should not be stored in the `web.config`. Neither should they be in the database, it's a waste of your DB processing power and bandwidth. A better way would be to use `resource files`. See this article about ASP.NET localization: [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228208%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)